# cannot log in with correct password and username. keep false

Tags: php, authentication

when I log in, even the password and username are correct, it keep error.

Array ( [0] => That user/password combination is incorrect )

the username and password is active and existed. 
**login.php**

```
    <?php
include 'init.php';

if(empty($_POST) === false){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['pwd1'];

if(empty($username)|| empty($password)) {
        echo 'You need to enter username and password';
    }
    else if(user_exists($username) === true){
        if(user_active($username) === true){

        $login = login($username, $password);
        if($login === false){
            $errors[] = 'That user/password combination is incorrect' ;

        } else{

            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
            ob_end_clean();
            header('Location:forum.php');
            exit();
        }
    }
    else{$errors[] = 'You haven\'t activated your account!';}
    }
    else{$errors[] = 'We can\'t find that username. Have you registered?';}

    print_r($errors);

}
?>
```

**users.php**

```
<?php
function logged_in(){
    return (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) ? true :false;
}
function user_exists($username){
    $username = sanitize($username);
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM `user` WHERE username = '$username'";
    $result = mysql_query( $sql);

    return (mysql_result($result,0) ==1) ? true : false;
}
function user_active($username){
    $username = sanitize($username);
    $sql ="SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM `user` WHERE username = '$username' AND `active` = 1";
    $result = mysql_query( $sql);
    if ($result === false){
        return false;

    }
        return (mysql_result($result,0) ==1) ? true : false;
}
function user_id_from_username($username){
    $username = sanitize($username);
    $sql = "SELECT user_id FROM `user` WHERE username = '$username'";
    $result = mysql_query( $sql);
    if ($result === false){
        return false;

    }
    return mysql_result($result,0, 'user_id');
}
function login($username, $password){

    $username = sanitize($username);
    $password = md5($password);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(user_id) 
        FROM `user`
        WHERE username ='$username' AND pwd1 ='$password'");

    $row = mysql_fetch_row($query); 
    if($row[0]>0){
        return user_id;
        }else{
            return false;
            } 

}

?>
```

**general.php**

```
<?php
function sanitize($data){
    return mysql_real_escape_string($data);}
?>
```

**init.php**

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

require 'connect.php';
require 'general.php';
require 'users.php';


$errors = array();
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't assign `$login` to `$_SESSION['user_id']`, because you call `die($login);` before that, which is same as exit, nothing is parsed after that. Change the order.

And pray that your sanitize function works. Anyway, you had better switch to PDO, because mysql_ functions are deprecated and not safe. Even if you sanitize your $_POST and $_GET, you can still have malicious values selected from your database or from XML you parse or from other source.

Comment: Still cannot work. I tried to use PDO but is not work for me.

Comment: check what your `login()` function returns - if there are two identical records, it will return false. You don't need to call `user_id_from_username` in `login()`, because you can return true instead of that `$user_id`

Comment: I delete the user_id_from_username. But still come up the error. Array ( [0] => That user/password combination is incorrect )

Comment: at least you know that it is something in `login()` function - just examine it and you will see. Run this query in phpmyadmin to see if it yields anything.

Comment: phpmyadmin shows   COUNT(user_id) =0.   That means the query is incorrect? I copy   SELECT COUNT(user_id) 
        FROM `user`
        WHERE username ='$username' AND pwd1 ='$password'

Comment: instead of $username and $password write existing user name and md5 of password.

Comment: its work , it shows COUNT(user_id) = 1. then what should i do?

Comment: check what is function login returnig by var_dump

Comment: ah yes, login returns false. I don't know mysql_result function, never used that. In last statement in login() I would make $row = mysql_fetch_row($query); if($row[0]>0){return true;}else{return false;}

Comment: function login($username, $password){

    $username = sanitize($username);
    $password = md5($password);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(user_id) 
        FROM `user`
        WHERE username ='$username' AND pwd1 ='$password'");

    $row = mysql_fetch_row($query); 
 if($row[0]>0){
  return true;
  }else{
   return false;
   } 
}

?>                                                                                still have error....

Comment: check what is in $row variable: print_r($row);

Comment: nothing change, still that error. I put it in users.php or login.php still not working.

Comment: this print_r was only for you to see what is in $row, it was not supposed to fix it. When you see what is in $row array, you will know if there is 0 key and what value it holds

Comment: actually you need that $user_id which login() was returning because it is put into session variable. But why this function returns false is not known from this code.

Comment: you should flush the buffer at the end and before header call ob_end_clean();

Comment: I added ob_end_clean(); before header, change the return true to user_id. But still got the error.

Comment: even my password have not use md5, still got error.

Comment: I don't know what might happen - after `mysql_query` in `login()` function add after final bracket  `or die(mysql_error())` - maybe it will say that there is some error?

Comment: die(mysql_error()) is in the function login() or outside? if inside, nothing changed; outside, blank page.